# cant add user to sudo group in centOS 7 i386(no GUI,Its minimal)

Tags: centos, command-line, sudo, users, privileges

I had install centOS 7 minimal version in my virtualbox in Ubuntu mate. It has no GUI. It is totally CLI. My user name is `Smit` and able to login in to it. But when i type command

```
sudo yum update
```

and enter my password, it says

```
Smit is not in sudoers files. This incident will be reported.
```

But when I try to add my user to `sudo` group by command

```
adduser Smit sudo
```

gives something like this:

[image]

(I am unable to copy-paste via virtual-box. I do this by login in root.)

Comment: i had used the command in both manner.without `<>` and with `<>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know why your command doesn't work. It may have to do with either:

- your CentOS not using sudo by default
- the way the sudoers file should be edited
- the syntax of `adduser` command on that particular machine.

Apparently, and it is my guess, it's first of all a matter of the last point.

Anyhow, the easiest way is to add the user to the `wheel` group, which should have sudo priviliges on your CentOS. Try out this command:

```
usermod -aG wheel Smit
```

This of course has to be done by `root`. Once successfully executed, change identity to `Smit` and check if you can `sudo`.

```
su - Smit
sudo yum update
```

As an alternative, you can use `visudo`. Adding this line should do:

```
Smit ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

But [here's a guide](http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/635) with a few more details if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add user Smit to group wheel which is have permission to run all commands with sudo command And you can accomplish it by entering the following command

> vim /etc/group

look for wheel group and add smit to it

[image]

save and exit and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the exact same situation with OP. Tried the same command and got the same result.

Then I used

```
usermod -aG sudo Smit
```

and got the result

```
The group "sudo" does not exist.
```

I think that is the reason `adduser Smit sudo` dose not work -- The group "sudo" does not exist yet!

The following command to add the user to the "wheel" group does work.

```
usermod -aG wheel Smit
```

But at this point, switching to user Smit and trying sudo still failed! I have to do one more thing. Use `visudo` to open and edit the /etc/sudoers file. Make sure that the line that starts with %wheel is not commented. It should look exactly like this:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

That is the final step to set up set up the account and now everything is OK.